# How prove this integral $\int_0^1\frac{(\arctan{x})^2\ln({x+1/x+2})}{(1+x)^2}dx$

Tags: integration, proof-verification, definite-integrals

$$I=\int_0^1\frac{(\arctan{x})^2\ln({x+1/x+2})}{(1+x)^2}dx=-\dfrac{\pi^3}{96}+\dfrac{5\pi}{16}\ln^22-\dfrac{\pi}{4}G-G+\dfrac{\pi}{2}\ln2+\dfrac{7}{16}\zeta(3)$$
 Where G is the Catalan's Constant.
 Using integration by parts we have:
 $$v=-\dfrac{1}{1+x},  du=[2\dfrac{\arctan{x}\ln(x+1/x+2)}{1+x^2}-\dfrac{(1-x)}{x(1+x)}{(\arctan{x})^2}]dx$$.
$$\dfrac{(1-x}{x(1+x)^2}=-\dfrac{1}{1+x}-\dfrac{2}{(1+x)^2}+\dfrac{1}{x}$$
$$\int_0^1\dfrac{(\arctan{x})^2}{x}dx=\dfrac{\pi}{2}G-\dfrac{7}{8}\zeta(3),\int_0^1\frac{(\arctan{x})^2}{(1+x)^2}dx=-\dfrac{G}{2}+\dfrac{\pi}{4}\ln2,\int_0^1\dfrac{(\arctan{x})^2}{1+x}dx=\dfrac{\pi}{4}G-\dfrac{21}{32}\zeta(3)+\dfrac{\pi^2}{32}\ln2$$
 $$ And \int_0^1\dfrac{(1-x)}{x(1+x)^2}{(\arctan{x})^2}dx=\dfrac{\pi}{4}G-\dfrac{7}{32}\zeta(3)-\dfrac{\pi^2}{32}\ln2+G-\dfrac{\pi}{2}\ln2$$
How to calculate$$\int_0^1\frac{\arctan{x}\ln({x+1/x+2})}{(1+x)(1+x^2)}dx??$$

Comment: $\int_0^1 \frac{\tan ^{-1}(x) \log \left(x+\frac{1}{x}+2\right)}{(1+x) \left(1+x^2\right)} \, dx=-\frac{\pi ^3}{192}+\frac{5}{32} \pi  \log
   ^2(2)+\frac{1}{192} \pi ^2 \log (8)+\frac{7 \zeta (3)}{64}$ by CAS.

Comment: Just an idea so far but first make the substitution $x\mapsto\frac {1-x}{1+x}$ and expand the product. The first integral is easily computed. The next two might be difficult, but try another round of substitutions $x\mapsto\frac {1-x}{1+x}$

Comment: I think Frank W. is right the use of the change of variable $x\mapsto\frac {1-x}{1+x}$ applied to the first integral makes the things easier IMHO. But you need to change a little the log. The expression inside is more or less $(1+x)^2$.

Comment: Perfect,it works.Thank you

Comment: why not write $\frac{\ln(x+\tfrac1{x}+2)}{(1+x)(1+x^2)}=\frac1{2}\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x^2}+\frac1{1+x}\right)(2\ln(1+x)-\ln x)$, and I think you can finish every items seperately.

Answer (score 2):

Break up the remaining integral as follows

\begin{align}
&\int_0^1\frac{\tan^{-1}{x}\ln({x+\frac1x+2})}{(1+x)(1+x^2)}dx\\
=& \ \frac12 \int_0^1\frac{(1-x)\tan^{-1}{x}\ln({x+\frac1x+2})}{(1+x)(1+x^2)}dx+\frac12 \int_0^1\frac{\tan^{-1}{x}\ln({x+\frac1x+2})}{1+x^2}dx\\
=&\ \frac12\left( -\frac{\pi^3}{96}+\frac{5\pi}{16}\ln^22\right) + \frac12\left(\frac7{32}\zeta(3)+\frac{\pi^2}{32}\ln2 \right)\\
= &\ \frac7{64}\zeta(3)- \frac{\pi^3}{192} + \frac{\pi^2}{64}\ln2 
+ \frac{5\pi}{32}\ln^22
\end{align}